# Js и svg вывод и редактирование

Tags: javascript

Есть 200+ svg файлов. 
При клике на определенную кнопку мне нужно вывести 4-7 файлов. потом при клике на другую кнопку изменить в этих файлах некоторые строчки. 
все это дело надо решить без использования node js и тому подобных фреймворков. 
Не прошу код и т.п. просто подтолкните на верный путь. 
Спасибо.

Comment: SVG -- суть XML. Работа из браузерного JS с ним мало чем отличается от работы с DOM. Подгружать изображения можно динамически создавая тег `svg`. Раз готовый код вам не нужен, то дальше сами.

Comment: можете пример показать?

Comment: Вы сами сказали, что код вам не нужен. А направление "куда копать" я вроде бы обозначил четко. Вполне возможно, что кто-то захочет решить задачу _за вас_. Я же делать этого не собираюсь.